# Highcharts are not working through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

Here is my code and the problem I'm facing is:-
This are the values which are coming from a page:-

```
    <?php 
    $avail=$_REQUEST['avail'];
    $issued=$_REQUEST['issued'];
    $bind=$_REQUEST['bind']; 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#books_status').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Books Status'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Status',
                    data: [
                        ['Availabe', <?php echo $avail; ?>],
                        ['Issues', <?php echo $issued; ?>],
                        ['Binding', <?php echo $bind; ?>]
                    ]
                }]
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="books_status"></div>
```

Now the problem is that by fetching values from a page and passing this values in above script, we are not able to generate a graph.

Please suggest.

==========================================================================================

Updated question:

This is my First HTML Page on which i have one Ajax function: libraryData('1')- through this function I'm getting data on this page.
HTML Page Code:

```
    <?php include_once 'library-header.php'; ?>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="container"><!-- container -->
    <div class="row" id="row-c1">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="content">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#panel-1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="libraryData('1')">Books Management</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel-1">
                <div class="row" id="option">
                    <div class="col-md-6 padding0px">
                        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control" onchange="getLibraryBooks(this.value, '1');">
                            <option value="-1">Select Status </option>
                            <option value="1">Available</option>
                            <option value="2">Issue</option>
                            <option value="3">Binding</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="library_data1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

    include_once 'library-footer.php';

    ?>
```

This is my second page that receive my first page request:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Number</th>
            <th>Book Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Book Location</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php
            $status=-1;
            if(isset ($_REQUEST['status']))
                $status=$_REQUEST['status'];

            if($status!=-1) {
                $query1="select library_books.lib_book_id book_id,library_books.lib_book_title as book_title,library_books.lib_book_author as  book_author,
library_books.lib_book_tag_id as book_tag , library_books.lib_book_status as book_status,library_racks.lib_racks_name as rack_name,
library_departments.lib_department_name as department
From  library_books,library_racks,library_departments
Where library_books.lib_rack_id=library_racks.lib_racks_id
AND library_racks.lib_department_id=library_departments.lib_department_id
AND lib_book_status=$status
Order By library_books.lib_book_id";
            }
            elseif($status==-1) {
                $query1="select library_books.lib_book_id book_id,library_books.lib_book_title as book_title,library_books.lib_book_author as  book_author,
library_books.lib_book_tag_id as book_tag , library_books.lib_book_status as book_status,library_racks.lib_racks_name as rack_name,
library_departments.lib_department_name as department
From  library_books,library_racks,library_departments
Where library_books.lib_rack_id=library_racks.lib_racks_id
AND library_racks.lib_department_id=library_departments.lib_department_id
Order By library_books.lib_book_id";
            }

            $result1=mysql_query($query1);
            $counter=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            $p=($counter/20)+1;
            $p=floor($p);
            if(($counter%20)==0)
                $p=$p-1;
            $count=0;
            if(isset ($_REQUEST['pid'])) {
                $id=$_REQUEST['pid'];
                $k=$id;
            }
            else {
                $id=0;
                $k=0;
            }
            $j=$k*20;

            $avail=0;
            $issued=0;
            $bind=0;

            $query=$query1."";

            $result=mysql_query($query);
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
            $i=1;
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                        <?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                        <?php echo $row['book_title']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                        <?php echo $row['book_author']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                        <?php echo $row['rack_name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                        <?php
                        if($row['book_status']==1) {
                            echo "Available";
                            $avail++;
                        }
                        elseif($row['book_status']==2) {
                            echo "Issue";
                            $issued++;
                        }
                        elseif($row['book_status']==3) {
                            echo "Binding";
                            $bind++;
                        }
                        ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="library-book-issue-info.php?book_id=<?php echo  $row['book_id']; ?>&status=<?php echo $row['book_status'];?>">View Book Info</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <?php
                $i++;
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <b>
                    Total Results: <?php echo $counter; ?>
                </b>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                    <?php
                    for( $i=0;$i<$p;$i++) { ?>
                <a href="javascript:paging('<?php echo $i; ?>','<?php echo $_REQUEST['page_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $_REQUEST['tab']; ?>','1');"><?php echo $i+1 ?></a>
                        <?php  } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#books_status').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Books Status'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Status',
                    data: [
                        ['Availabe', <?php echo $avail; ?>],
                        ['Issues', <?php echo $issued; ?>],
                        ['Binding', <?php echo $bind; ?>]
                    ]
                }]
        });
    });

    </script>


    <div id="books_status" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

    </div>
```

==============================================================================
AJAX Function:

```
    function libraryData(subtab)
    {
    var page_id=document.getElementById("page_id").value;
    var tab=document.getElementById("tab").value;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("library_data"+subtab).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","library-data-table.php?page_id="+page_id+"&tab="+tab+"&    subtab="+subtab,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the $_REQUESTS returns the proper values? Echo them out to see them if they are correct. If not, you have problem with you data passing.

Comment: There is no problem with values. Page returns correct values.

Comment: I will post a longer answer to what maybe cause it.

Comment: Your php variables returns a number or string?

Comment: You just need to paste the rendered HTML Source, with all the datas and JS. Not the PHP and SQL queries.

Comment: Why you cannot return a json in php, and then load in the javascript by $.getJSON(). The code will be clear adn you avoid problems with communications/type of data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the highcharts.js in the file too?
Also try to use $ document on ready.

The code should be like this:

```
     <?php 
        $avail=$_REQUEST['avail'];
        $issued=$_REQUEST['issued'];
        $bind=$_REQUEST['bind']; 
        ?>
     <script src="highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $('#books_status').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Books Status'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Status',
                        data: [
                            ['Availabe', <?php echo $avail; ?>],
                            ['Issues', <?php echo $issued; ?>],
                            ['Binding', <?php echo $bind; ?>]
                        ]
                    }]
            });
    });
    </script>
  <div id="books_status"></div>
```

Comment: I includes all js files in header page and also replace above code in my page but graph is not rendering.

Comment: Does it give back any error if you use anykind of debug? Chrome debug or Firefox firebug? Or maybe.... Give width and height to your div. This worked for me,but you should give width too.
<div id="books_status" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

Comment: No its not working and the result is not displaying ....... so please suggest me any other idea for this please i am in need of it...

Comment: Can you please update your question with the full source of HTML which AJAX post back? Then I can watch it through and find the problem.

Comment: This is my First HTML Page on which i have one ajax function: libraryData('1')

Comment: Edit your question and post it there. In here you cannot paste long code.

Comment: sir i updated my question please see it and sugggest me please